# Lambda expressions as CLR (.NET) delegates / event handlers in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: .net, events, delegates, lambda, c++-cli

Is it possible to use the new lambda expressions in Visual C++ 2010 as CLR event handlers? I've tried the following code:

```
SomeEvent += gcnew EventHandler(
    [] (Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
        // code here
    }
);
```

It results in the following error message:

> error C3364: 'System::EventHandler' : invalid argument for delegate constructor; delegate target needs to be a pointer to a member function

Am I attempting the impossible, or is simply my syntax wrong?

Comment: Check my solution "Lambda2Delegate" posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26552573/2604941

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No can do, the C++/CLI compiler didn't get updated to accept the lambda syntax.  Fairly ironic btw given the head-start that managed code had.

Comment: It is indeed. I wonder if this something to do with the capture clause semantics, which does not exist in CLR. As far as I understand C# lambdas are something like `[&, &this]` - as in lambda can modify whatever is in its parent's scope, so they could have just mandated that C++ lambdas must have such capture clause.

Comment: That's too bad, it looks a bit messy with a throw-away class inside the function that creates the handler, just to contain a member function. :/

Comment: CLR can deal with unmanaged pointers (which is what &-references are translated to), so it could be done - it just wouldn't be verifiable. I believe it just isn't something that they wanted to take time to implement. I have a Connect feature request logged for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524356/add-managed-lambdas-to-c-cli - upvote if you want this.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. I do actually have some code lying around that lets you wrap lambdas (and any function objects, really) into delegates - it lets you write things such as: `Func<int, int, int>^ f1 = make_delegate([&](int x, int y) { return x + y; });`. The problem with it is that, since synthesized lambda type is unmanaged, it cannot contain managed types - which means that such lambda cannot capture managed object references (`T^`). You can use `gcroot<T>` instead, of course, but it's still inconvenient, and I do wonder about perf implications. Anyway, I can share the code if you want.

Comment: @absence: it doesn't take a "throw-away class" to implement an event handler.  A simple member function gets the job done.

Comment: @Hans: this requires a class in the first place (who says that the code registering an event has to be in a class?), and then it also requires a `ref class`. Furthermore, a lambda also captures the surrounding environment, and you have to do it manually for a member function.

Comment: @Pavel: Yes please, it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 9):

The following is my solution that allows one to wrap lambdas (as well as any function objects - i.e. anything on which `operator()` can be called) into delegates. It has some limits - specifically, it doesn't support delegates with tracking reference parameters (`%` in C++/CLI, `ref`/`out` in C#); and it has an upper limit on the number of parameters the delegate can take (because VC++2010 doesn't suppport vararg templates) - though the code can be trivially adjusted to support up to as many as you want.

```
#pragma once

#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    struct return_type_helper
    {
    private:

        template<class D>
        struct dependent_false { enum { value = false }; };

        template <class D>
        struct illegal_delegate_type
        {
            static_assert(dependent_false<D>::value, "Delegates with more than 2 parameters, or with parameters of tracking reference types (T%), are not supported.");
        };

        struct anything
        {
            template<class T>
            operator T() const;
        };

    public:

        template<class D>
        static decltype(static_cast<D^>(nullptr)()) dummy(int(*)[1]);

        template<class D>
        static decltype(static_cast<D^>(nullptr)(anything())) dummy(int(*)[2]);

        template<class D>
        static decltype(static_cast<D^>(nullptr)(anything(), anything())) dummy(int(*)[3]);

        template <class D>
        static illegal_delegate_type<D> dummy(...);
    };


    template<class Func, class Aligner = char, bool Match = (std::tr1::alignment_of<Func>::value == std::tr1::alignment_of<Aligner>::value)>
    struct aligner
    {
        static_assert(Match, "Function object has unsupported alignment");
    };

    template<class Func, class Aligner>
    struct aligner<Func, Aligner, true>
    {
        typedef Aligner type;
    };

    template<class Func>
    struct aligner<Func, char, false> : aligner<Func, short>
    {
    };

    template<class Func>
    struct aligner<Func, short, false> : aligner<Func, int>
    {
    };

    template<class Func>
    struct aligner<Func, int, false> : aligner<Func, long>
    {
    };

    template<class Func>
    struct aligner<Func, long, false> : aligner<Func, long long>
    {
    };

    template<class Func>
    struct aligner<Func, long long, false> : aligner<Func, double>
    {
    };

    template<class Func>
    struct aligner<Func, double, false> : aligner<Func, void*>
    {
    };


    template<class F>
    ref class lambda_wrapper
    {
    public:

        lambda_wrapper(const F& f)
        {
            pin_ptr<F> pf = (interior_ptr<F>)&f_storage;
            new(pf) F(f);
        }

        ~lambda_wrapper()
        {
            pin_ptr<F> pf = (interior_ptr<F>)&f_storage;
            pf->~F();
        }

        template <class D>
        operator D^ ()
        {
            D^ d = nullptr;
            return gcnew D(this, &lambda_wrapper<F>::invoke<decltype(return_type_helper::dummy<D>(0))>);
        }

    private:

        template<class T>
        [System::Runtime::InteropServices::StructLayout(System::Runtime::InteropServices::LayoutKind::Sequential, Size = sizeof(T))]
        value struct embedded_storage
        {
        private:
            typename aligner<T>::type dummy;
        };


        embedded_storage<F> f_storage;

        template<class R>
        R invoke()
        {
            pin_ptr<F> pf = (interior_ptr<F>)&f_storage;
            return (*pf)();
        }

        template<class R, class A1>
        R invoke(A1 a1)
        {
            pin_ptr<F> pf = (interior_ptr<F>)&f_storage;
            return (*pf)(a1);
        }

        template<class R, class A1, class A2>
        R invoke(A1 a1, A2 a2)
        {
            pin_ptr<F> pf = (interior_ptr<F>)&f_storage;
            return (*pf)(a1, a2);
        }
    };
}

template<class F>
detail::lambda_wrapper<F>^ make_delegate(F f)
{
    return gcnew detail::lambda_wrapper<F>(f);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Func<int, String^, int>^ f2 = make_delegate([&](int x, String^ y) -> int {
    Console::WriteLine("Func {0} {1}", x, y);
    return 2;
});
```

While this technically does what you want, the practical applications are somewhat limited due to the fact that C++0x lambdas are expanded into plain classes, not `ref` or `value` ones. Since plain classes cannot contain managed types in C++/CLI (i.e. no members of object handle type, no members of tracking reference type, and no members of `value class` type), this means that lambdas cannot capture any variables of those types, either. There is no workaround I'm aware of for tracking references. For `value class`, you can take an unmanaged pointer to it (`pin_ptr` if needed), and capture that.

For object handles, you can store them in `gcroot<T>`, and capture that - but there are severe performance implications - in my tests, accessing a member via `gcroot<T>` is about 40x times slower than doing it using a plain object handle. It's actually not much in absolute measure for a single call, but for something that is called repeatedly in a loop - say, most LINQ algorithms - it would be a killer. But note that this only applies when you need to capture a handle in the lambda! If you just use it to write a predicate inline, or to update a counter, it'll work just fine.

Comment: This seems to fail with LNK2022 if I call it for lambdas with the same type but which capture different things. I assume that the size of the generated type is different while the type is the same. Is there any fix for this or am I just way of base with my theory anyway?

Comment: Sarien, what do you mean by "lambdas of the same type capturing different things"? Every C++ lambda has its own unique type, even if the signatures match, and even if the capture lists match.

Answer (score -1):

This page has a few examples of lambdas for C++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Microsoft VS2010 C++ improvements look like they actually implement [C++0x lambda spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions). As such they are purely unmanaged and are of type `lambda`.

There is nothing in the Microsoft documentation that hints at possibility of using C++ lambdas as CLR lambdas. At this stage I have to say that you cannot use C++ lambdas as handlers for managed delegates.