# Additional parameters for FileSystemEventHandler in c++/cli

Tags: .net, c++-cli

i would like to convert this code (working code in c#) in c++/cli

```
        static private void onChange(object s, FileSystemEventArgs e, string customArg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
        Console.WriteLine(customArg);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string customArg = "myCustomArg";

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = "G:\\";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // i cannot convert this line in c++/cli
        watcher.Changed += (s, e) => onChange(s, e, customArg);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

there is my code in c++/cli

```
void FileWatcher::onChanged(Object^ source, FileSystemEventArgs^ e, String^ customArg)
{
   Console::WriteLine(e->FullPath);
   Console::WriteLine(customArg);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FileSystemWatcher watcher->Path = "G:\\";
   watcher->IncludeSubdirectories = true;
   watcher->NotifyFilter = static_cast<System::IO::NotifyFilters>    (NotifyFilters::LastWrite);

   String^ customArg = gcnew String("myArg");

   // this line not compile
   watcher->Changed += (s, e) = > onChange(s, e, customArg);
   //
}
```

i tried to use lambda function like this

```
watcher->Changed += [](Object^ s, FileSystemEventArgs^ e, String^ c) -> void { OnChange(s, e, c); };
```

but it's not working , probably doing wrong

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777445/lambda-expressions-as-clr-net-delegates-event-handlers-in-visual-c-2010 you can't assign a lambda as a delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can't do this through a lambda so you have to make a class that poses as the event handler, something similar to this.

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

void GlobalOnChanged(Object^ source, FileSystemEventArgs^ e, String^ customArg)
{
    Console::WriteLine(e->FullPath);
    Console::WriteLine(customArg);
}

public ref class Invoker
{
public:
    Invoker(String^ customArg) : customArg_(customArg)
    {

    }
    void OnChanged(Object^ source, FileSystemEventArgs^ e)
    {
        GlobalOnChanged(source, e, customArg_);
    }

private:
    String^ customArg_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FileSystemWatcher^ watcher = gcnew FileSystemWatcher;
    watcher->Path = "C:\\";
    watcher->IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher->NotifyFilter = static_cast<System::IO::NotifyFilters>    (NotifyFilters::LastWrite);
    String^ customArg = gcnew String("myArg");
    watcher->Changed += gcnew FileSystemEventHandler(gcnew Invoker(customArg), &Invoker::OnChanged);
}
```

Comment: Note that when you write a lambda in C#, the C# compiler produces something *very* similar to this. Class `Invoker` would have fields for the extra parameters that need to be passed to that method, as shown here, and for the method to be called as well.

Comment: @David I thought you were crazy for not just doing a lambda capture of customArg. Turns out there are no managed lambdas in c++/cli. Giant hole in the language.